# Como separar os digitos de um número atribuído a uma variável de tipo int utilizando um ponteiro de tipo char?

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro

```
#include <stdio.h>

void separaDigitos(int num, char *digitos) {
//onde deveria haver o código da função
}

int main(void) {
  int num;
  char digitos[10];
  printf("Digite um número: ");
  scanf("%d", &num);
  separaDigitos(num, digitos);
  for (int i = 0; digitos[i]; i++)
    printf("digito[%d] = %c\n", i, digitos[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

```
Input:
80
```

```
Output:
digito[0]=8
digito[1]=0
```

O objetivo é criar uma função que separa os digitos de um número digitado pelo usuário e retorne os digitos dele separadamente. Por favor, me ajudem nessa, não tenho nem ideia do que fazer!

Answer (score 1):

Podes utilizar a função sprintf:

```
void separaDigitos(int num, char *digitos) {
    sprintf(digitos, "%d", num);
}
```

Comment: muitoooo obrigado!!!!